# Pandas - Parsing Bank Statement

Tags: python, parsing, pandas

I have 2 dataframes - transactions and companies.

Transactions comes from a csv directly from the bank. There is a column "booking text" which has a long string with the details of the transaction, these strings vary depending on a number of factors but for the most part look sort of like this:

> "Company Co. DERFTHD DE89758975869857 657878987 End-to-End-Ref:. FRG.3.GH.15789"

Companies is a list of companies with two columns - "search key" and "company name" which I have populated in order to search these "booking text" strings and return company names.

I want to create a new column in the transactions frame which uses the "search key" and contains the "company name"

EDIT: Sorry - I am a total newb at this. Let me try again.

So I have a dataframe of names

```
In [1]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([['cat','Bob'], ['dog','Joe'],['bird','Lary']], 
              columns=['A','B'])
Out[2]: df1
      A      B
0    cat    Bob
1    dog    Joe
2    bird   Lary
```

and a dataframe of strings (as well as other columns)

```
In [3]: df2 = pd.DataFrame([['the cat is big','2'],['the cat is small', 4],
              ['the dog is small',3]], columns=['C','D']
Out[4]:
            C            D
0    the cat is big      2
1    the cat is small    4
2    the dog is small    3
```

I want to be able to create a new column "E" in df2 which contains the "subject" of the string in column C based on the information in df1.

So "the cat is big" contains "cat" and so the value should be "Bob"

My desired output is this.

```
Out[5]: df3
             C           D     E
0    the cat is big      2    Bob
1    the cat is small    4    Bob
2    the dog is small    3    Joe
```

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you looking for a merge on `search key`? Is the `search key` contained in the `transactions` dataframe somehow?

Comment: Please check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Look for pd.concat

Answer (score 3):

create a dictionary for df1 instead of a dataframe.

`df1_dict = {'cat':'Bob', 'dog':'Joe', 'bird':'Lary' }`

`for key, value in df1_dict.iteritems(): 
    df2.loc[df2['C'].str.contains(key),'E'] = value`

`print df2`